# Regular Expression question

Tags: html, regex

Expert

I swear I surf a lot of regular expression stuff to study but I find regular expression topic is too difficult to me understand. Any good suggestion for me?

Anyone can explain to me why this `<p[^>]*>` can simply remove the start `<p>` or `<p attr="">`?
And what could I do,  if I want make it from

```
<div style="float: left; width: 350px; border: 1px solid #000000;" class="star1">abcdk</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="star1">abcdk</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read some tutorials, experiment, and don't parse HTML with regex. ;-) I'd suggest http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html even if you are not into Perl.

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML/XML is a losing battle.  It's like using a screwdriver to hammer nails.  You can do it with a lot of work but it's not a good solution.  Please read the first answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: [The `<center>` cannot hold it is too late](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: Play around with a [regex tester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) to get the hang of what matches what.

Jason's explanation was good, but maybe not in-depth enough for you if you're just starting out with regexes. Let's take `<p[^>]*>` a piece at a time:

- `<` has no special meaning to regex engines, so it means it just matches a single `<`
- p is the same: match a single p
- [ is a special character. Square braces in regex mean "any of these". For instance, the regex `[abc]` would match any single character that is 'a', 'b', or 'c'.
- ^ is a special character with two possible meanings. When inside of square brackets, like it is here, it's a simple negation. Whereas `[abc]` would match any single character mentioned, `[^abc]` would match any single character *not* mentioned.
- `>` has no special meaning: just match a single `>`
- ] should be obvious to you by now: it closes the opening [
- * is a special character that says match 0 or more of what came before it; that means it could match nothing, or it could match a huge amount of stuff, as long as it all matches what comes before the *.
- `>` still no special meaning, like earlier

So we can break `<p[^>]*>` into three pieces, and we can say that it matches any series of characters:

- `<p`: that starts with a literal `<p`,
- `[^>]*`: which is followed by 0 or more characters that are not a `>`,
- `>`: and which ends with a literal `>`.

Oh, and http://www.regular-expressions.info is one of the best regex guides I've ever found online.

Comment: just want to remove the style things in div tag

Comment: Ah, I see. When I first looked at it, it must not have been showing the code blocks. There was nothing there.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for the question that I can now see.

Comment: Ryan, you are my great teacher. Make everything so clear to me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please remember to accept an answer if your problems are cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p[^>]*>
```

Matches `<p` with any character except `>` ending with a `>`. In this case a `<p>` tag with or without attributes.

For a `<div>` tag, you could simply modify the regex above. A simple example being:

```
<div[^>]* class="star1">
```

For something more flexible (i.e. class attribute doesn't have to be at the end):

```
<div[^>]*class="star1"[^>]*>
```

I'd encourage you to learn more about regular expressions. They are a very powerful tool.